# Question from a past exam: Prove $dim(Im(T))=Tr(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

Found this question from a past exam.

Let $E:V \rightarrow V$ be the projection operator on a finite-dimensional vector-space $V$ over $F$.

1) Prove $V=Im(E) \oplus Ker(E)$

(I believe I proved this one but I'd like to see a more certain proof.)

2) Prove $dim(Im(E))=Tr(E)$.

Specifically: find a base $B$ of $V$ such that $dim(Im(E))=Tr([E]_B)$

I am clueless about number 2.

Comment: What definition of projection do you know? The sentence "the projection operator over $F$" is ambiguous since one may project onto $F$ in many different ways. Also, the name of your operator seems to change from $E$ to $T$ between the two questions !

Comment: It's the vector space that is "over $F$"

Comment: @ancientmathematician I see, $F$ is a field !

Comment: Here's a clue for (2): once you've proved (1) you know you can get a basis of $V$ by taking the union of any basis of $Im(E)$ and any basis of $Ker(E)$. Then ...

Comment: $E^2=E $ so $E(I-E)=0$ and $x=Ex+(I-E)x $. For part 2, you need $b_i $ (basis vectors st) $Tb_i=b_i $ for the $dim (Im (T)) $ of these vectors, zero otherwise.

Comment: @ancientmathematician so I got a basis which is the union of the bases of ImE, KerE. How would I know the Trace of the final matrice?

Comment: Trace is the sum of eigenvalues so you have a $1$ for each vector in a basis for $\Im (T)$ and a $0$ for each vector in a basis for $Ker (T)$. Thus you see that the trace is the same as the dimension of the image.

Comment: I would just add that as stated the result (2) is False. One needs in general the extra condition that the characteristic of $F$ is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. a. For $v \in V$, $v = Ev + v - Ev$ and use the fact that $E^2 = E$.

   b. $Im(E) \cap Ker(E) = \{0\}$ is easy to see.
2. (*Based on the assumption that V is finite dim.*) Use the fact that the eigenvalues of $E$ are all $1$ or $0$ because it's a projection.

If you aren't able to finish the proof based on this info, do comment and I'll add more hints.

Cheers!